# MongoDB aggregate с пустым полем - массив

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Как быть?
Нежны перебрать комменты в документе, и вывести весь документ, но если комментов нет, то получается и документа нет =)

Вот пример структуры

```
{
    "url": "",
    "title": "",
    "comments": 
    [{
        "text": "",
        "pid": ""
    },{
        "text": "",
        "pid": ""
    }]

}
```

Нужно отсортировать комментарии по полю PID (Number)

После различных извращений и попыток добиться нужного результата ни к чему так и не пришел.

Вот пример последней вариации выборки

```
Coll.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "url": params.any
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "data": {
            "$first": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "url": "$url",
                "title": "$title",
            }
        },
        "comments": {
            "$first": "$comments"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$comments"
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "comments.pid": 1
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "data": {
            "$first": "$data"
        },
        "comments": {
            "$push": "$comments"
        }
    }
}]).exec(.....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отсортировать документы по полю `pid` из коллекции `comments` можно двумя способами:

```
db.test1.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "comments.pid": 1 } }
]);
```

или просто:

```
db.test1.find().sort( { "comments.pid": 1 } )
```

Думаю, перевести эти запросы на `node.js` не составит труда.

Comment: Боженьки! Я целый день страдал, и все же сделал сортировку на фронтенде, а тут такая новость! ))) Спасибо большое, это то что нужно.